# Can we refresh the VF page in a Console automatically , once a record is saved through the standard functionality?

Tags: apex, visualforce, console

I have been trying to implement a logic in Service Console. I have a VF page with a button "New Contact" which opens a new sub-tab for Contact record creation. Once the record is saved by clicking the standard "Save" button on the Contact page, the VF page needs to be refreshed automatically.
Can someone assist as the page does not refresh automatically with the standard "Save" functionality in Service Console?

Comment: Have you explored custom buttons?, you can execute a javascript on custom buttons and probably get this?